# A low noise multiplexer

Tags: analog, sensor, signal-processing

I am trying to make Faraday's cups array sensor, in which each signal coming from the cups must be amplified because it is too small (microampere or even lower).
But since I have too many cups, I need more than one amplifier circuit. So what I thought is to use multiplexer and only one amplifier circuit in this format:
[image]

The capacitors are like a memory for the charges coming from the cups, then I am going to pass the signals one by one to the amplifier circuit.
My question is: if there is no problem with idea of capacitors as memories, is the multiplexer able to pass the signals without losing it due to internal noise and internal capacitance?

Comment: how often and fast do you anticipate switching?

Comment: I want it to be controlable switching

Comment: you need to give some idea of speed. If you only want to switch every minute, you can perhaps do it with relays. If you want to do it at 1MHz, it's an entirely different problem. 1GHz, a different problem again.

Comment: After i asked... I have a range till 72 MHz and as I was infromed the faster the better since the capacitors loss there charge with time

Comment: good luck. I think doing this at that speed and not degrading performance will require very serious design effort, if it is possible at all. i would suggest you ask yourself whether the saving in hardware with this approach will justify the design effort and problems that you will very likely encounter. Unless you intend to produce this gadget in high volume (in which case you wouldn't be working alone), it probably is not. Just my take on it.

Comment: well noted, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That really doesn't sound sensible; you want to amplify a signal before you put it through a noisy active component. Also, hmm, nontrivial to build a multiplexer that does not disturb the operation of electromagnetic measurement device.

Sure, your capacitors will accept charge, but how much depends on what their potentials are  you would have to ground the other end. In your current configuration they just act as a series capacitor to the Faraday Cup, which in itself is a capacitor, and series capacitors just reduce the amount of available current. So, that is terrible for your measurement.

You could use the capacitors differently: one end connected to the Faraday Cup, the other grounded. That way they become current-integrating devices whose voltage friend on the amount of charges flown into them. That's going to, however, mean your measurement will have to be voltage-based and deal with very small voltage. It's not clear what you gain that way, either, as the Cups in themselves have exactly that propose of collecting charges, so simply not having another capacitor is the winning choice here.

Furthermore, semiconductor multiplexers have leakage currents which might well be within the range of the currents coming from your cup. So I'm assuming you're planning on using MEMS or classical relays. Make sure the parasitic capacitances of these doesn't add chargers that did not come from the cup!

In all honesty, you have multiple sensitive measurements, changes are you need to amplify each one individually. I'm not informed of how much charges your Faraday Cups collect, but chances are a low-noise amplifier would be less complicated to build than you think. A capacitive transimpedance amplifier would do the job - and you'd just realize by taking an opamp, connecting its non-inverting input to ground, connecting your Cup to the inverting input and having a capacitor between its output and the inverting input:

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/65/Transimpedanzverstaerker2.png]
(replace R with a capacitor) (image is public domain)

You'd choose an operational amplifier that has low input bias and low noise. Admittedly, these aren't cheap, but we're taking single-digit euros here, not lab measurement device cost. The closer you keep the amplifier circuit to the current source (Faraday Cup), the fewer stray effects you get, and the lower your noise figure becomes.

Since you do have a single channel measurement system, and assuming you have a somewhat reliable source of ions, you can first characterize what you see with your lab measurement so setup from a cup, then disconnect the measurement equipment, connect you capacitive transimpedance amplifier, and measure the voltage. Do that for two different ion beam intensities, to get a voltage per ion sensitivity figure.

Comment: they are just capacitors, just like your Cup. They store charge. They don't do anything useful to your application that the cup can't do on its own.

Comment: I see the problem the capacitor connection and yes they should be connected as you mentioned, however I think they are necessary if I want to implement a multiplexer. The idea is that when the ions hit the cups they are going to induce a current through them, each current depends on the amount of ions that hits, without the capacitors I will loss my input before being able to switch and amplify it  I found that buying one LMC6001 amplifier  and a TMUX7208 multiplexer is cheaper than buying 10op-amps (10 faraday's cups),

Comment: the are charging the cups. your cups *are* capacitors. Your added capacitors are not doing anything your cups don't do themselves. I'm repeating myself. The ions don't induce current, they introduce charge, current only flows if you connect a cup to a different potential. This is all really really basic theory (like, school physics, 9th grade), so I'll stop repeating myself.

Comment: Ok then this point is understood, so now going back to the original question.... you are saying that a multiplexer do have a leakage current and I can not use it for this application, but the data sheet of the TMUX7208 shows that it has a low on and off leakage currents allowing them to be used in high precision measurement applications. Can I still use it ?

Comment: I really don't see the point of repeating, word for word, what I wrote in my answer, sorry.

Comment: My bad ..... I didn't see your last paragraph...... any ways thanks for your time